# Is there an established name for position that argues against law?

Tags: political-philosophy, terminology, philosophy-of-law

This is my position. But for some reason I'm sure I'm not the first to accept it (I guess some anarchists would have it). So, there likely should be other people with this position. Is there a name for it? Or is it unnamed?

Under 'law' I mean enforceable rules, with judgement and conviction, typically associated with the state. A standard idea is that it is good or even necessary for society to have such rules. Thus, to argue against law is to argue that we need no such laws.

Comment: What law? Natural? Criminal? Argues how?

Comment: @Conifold Legal law. Argues how does not matter.

Comment: [Legal nihilism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legal_nihilism)?

Comment: @Conifold I think it is correct.

Comment: In the US Constitution, Article 1 Section 9 provides limits on legislative power. A little further on, Amendment 9 of the Bill of Rights states very clearly: *The enumeration in the Constitution, of certain rights, shall not be construed to deny or disparage others retained by the people.* The implication is that there are important human rights which naturally belong to people. Incidentally, it was my father who taught me the importance of understanding my rights as a human being and citizen of my country.

Comment: @Bread I know there are such notions as rights, duties, laws, etc. Yet, I don't think they all are really useful. That is, they would be obsolete in the world where people treat each other as friends and they are obstacles in the world where people treat strangers as *subjects*. Obstacles to reach the world where everyone (who is capable of friendship) treats everyone (who is capable for freidndship) as a friend.

Comment: @rus9384 So it is of Legal nihilism that you speak, according to your previous comment. Where rule of law is replaced by rule of *power*. Which has nothing at all to do with friendship, and is rather quite subjective. On the contrary, I would ideally prefer to see *self-governing* by people who as you put it are *capable of friendship*. I like how it is described in Jeremiah 31:33 (KJV) -- *After those days, said the Lord, I will put my law in their inward parts, and write it in their hearts; and will be their God, and they shall be my people.*

Comment: @Bread Well, there are people who think in terms of rights. And there are people who think in terms of possibilities. I am of second category. Maybe that's what you mean by power. But that doesn't make me an uncompassionate unfriendly bastard. But still, you do not play judges (like in courts, where all the people have to stand up and where there is a strict formal procedure) with friends. Indeed, you may criticize each other, but that's not what legalism is.

Comment: @rus9384 You would be surprised how easily a code of law pops up in human communities, even if they are quite small and isolated. The judgment->conviction->punishment process is no different from a parent asking a crying child "what happened?" and then deploying punishment as needed on the sibling that caused the injury, just on a very different scale. The mechanism, the underlying idea, however, isn't that different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is important to realize that "established" positions that argue against the law may be difficult to find. "Established" means "socially recognized" here, and that is not likely to occur because of a normal bias: human societies do not tend to look favorably at philosophies that challenge their own basic principles (let us consider it as a stimulus-response mechanism for self-preservation).

It does not mean that such positions against the law do not exist, or they would not have any validity, etc... It means, however, that they are less likely to get credence in a human society; or if they do, any state (including "democratic" ones) are unfortunately likely to put their promoters on a list of suspects, or actively suppress them, since police are established as:

> A body of government employees trained in methods of law enforcement
>   and crime prevention and detection and authorized to maintain the
>   peace, safety, and order of the community. ([American Heritage](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=police))

That being said, refusal of any form of government would go under the heading of [anarchism](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/anarchism/), which according to the [Online Etymology Dictionary](https://www.etymonline.com/word/anarchy) derives from Greek: *an* (absence) + *archia* (government); to which the suffix *-ism* is added to denote the philosophy.

> Please note that even though the state is what enforces the law, there
>   might be a subtle distinction between rejection of the state and
>   outright rejection of *any* social law (which would be [nihilism](https://www.britannica.com/topic/nihilism), from Latin *nihil*, nothing and *-ism*).

An intellectual figure of anarchism was [Peter Alekseyevich Kropotkin](https://www.britannica.com/biography/Peter-Alekseyevich-Kropotkin) (1842-1921), a learned man who promoted a new form of social organization based on cooperatives.

His theories were not particularly well received by the government of Imperial Russia; Western European states were not favorable either to anarchists (it is important to remember at that time that **anarchist** was the common name of what we call today a **terrorist**; so anybody who claimed to be an anarchist risked being put on police surveillance; and if some political figure got killed, they were on the list of prime suspects).

Experience seems to indicate that if someone intends to pursue **anarchism** as a form of active, social philosophy (rather than theoretical philosophy, or intellectual history, etc.), their mileage may vary, but freedom of thought is all what they might get (*providing* they live in a democratic state were civic rights are respected). In general, they might not get all the social support and public funding they might expect. And if they become "established" in some way, they will probably be graced with a fat file at the competent state security agency.

It is a paradaox that a society where rule of law exists and is respected, might be the only place were anarchists do not risk being brutalized by the police (or worse, by thugs or an angry mob). As a self-preservation measure, I would suggest to anyone who harbors elevated anarchist feelings, to first support the rule of law with all their heart.

Comment: If there is no established term for something, that thing is not important enough. I hold this position. My own position is that there can exist rules how to act, either in everyday life, or in experimental science. But the optimal idea is to assume that humans are above rules. No rule should be placed in the absolute, because a rule is something like a manual based on experiences, knowledge. And as we live we acknowledge more things. That's why placing rules to the absolute is a bad idea. So, I don't know if this position is nihilism as you put it.

Comment: I see that there may be a misunderstanding about the meaning of **position**, as in "established position" (Position: *A point of view or attitude on a certain question*, American Heritage). The **established term** does exist: anarchism or else nihilism. The issue was if a sufficient number of people are likely to support or at least tolerate that *position* so that it can be considered *established*.

Comment: Regarding your last paragraph. I disagree. Well, I agree with it if we talk about crude anti-law position. That is of permissiveness. My philosophy is: friendly => good, unfriendly => bad. Hence I take a position that I never **justify** my deeds. But I elaborate on them. Which means I won't tell people why I did something if they start from an assumption that I acted badly. That is an unfriendly assumption. But it is imprinted into legal systems.

Comment: No problem: what you are talking about is a personal moral code or a sense of ethics, which transcends the need for a law. Mine is a utilitarian observation and disregards whether states are moral entities or not; merely that when states perceive a threat, real or imaginary, they will hit back hard. And since states *do* commit injustices occasionally (especially when they feel threatened), it is best to have the rule of law as a shield if that happens. Hence a self-professed anarchist might need a lawyer and hope that the justice system works sufficiently well to pull her/him out of trouble.

Comment: Or anarchists just need to unite into a strong enough force (real one, not a legal one) to be capable of overcoming it.

Comment: This is getting lengthy (and might have to end as chat), but let me conclude thus: What you describe would qualify as [sedition](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=sedition). Let us hope, for your own sake, that yours is only an intellectual exercise.